# не отрабатывает метод setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Задача вообще такая,по нажатию на элемент списка,открывается новое окно.Но метод setOnItemClickListener() вообще не отрабатывает.Логи в метод засунул,вообще метод не задействуется. Голову сломал уже.Может туплю где,подскажите.

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private String[] list = new String[100];


public ListAdapter(Context context,String[]list){
    this.context=context;
    this.inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.list=list;
}




@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.list.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, null);
    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvListView)).setText(this.list[position]);
    Button btnList = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ImageView imageView =(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivListItem);

    return v;
}
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

final String[] list = new String[100];

private  static final String TAG = "myLog";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    initList(list);
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);


    final ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this,list);

    if (listView != null) {
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {

                Log.d(TAG,"метод OnItemClick");

            }
        });
    }
}

public void initList(String[] list){
    for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){
        list[i]=i+" ";
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onSettingsMenuClick(MenuItem item) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent,0);

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551042/onitemclicklistener-not-working-in-listview-android И это... закругляйтесь с ListView к тому же без Holder'а, recyclerView - наше все.

Comment: Есть вариант, что вы не просто логи не видите? Если у Вас список выводится, то адаптер будет работать. Попробуйте Toast запихать. Так-то ошибок явных нет, есть парочка ненужных строчек в адаптере, должно всё работать.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei клик не проходит из-за Button'а, который focusable...

Comment: ну да кончено, в разметке кнопка висит всё верно. Я про эти строчки и говорил

Comment: Ни логи ни тосты не появляются.viewholder добавил,тут разобрался,благодарю.А как снять фокус с кнопки,чтобы список адекватно работал?

Comment: все,разобрался,фокус поставил false и заработало!БЛАГОДАРЮ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте для вашей кнопки:

```
android:focusable="false"
```