# При добавлении RatingBar в ListView. Он (ListView) перестает реагировать на клики

Tags: android, listview, ratingbar

Какая- то фантастика. При добавлении RatingBar в ListView. Он (ListView) перестает реагировать на клики. Но если его (RatingBar) сделать INVISIBLE то все работает. Переходы по пунктам ListView начинают осуществляться.

Где-то прочитал что рейтинг бар типа перекрывает своей видимостью листвью и надо его позади поставить. Только вот как не пойму. Подскажите пожалуйста.

код адаптера ():

```
    Context context;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
ArrayList<News> newsArrayList;
ImageView imageView_listNews;
RatingBar ratingBar_news_list;

public NewsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<News> newsArrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.newsArrayList = newsArrayList;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return newsArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return newsArrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if(view == null) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_news_adapter, parent, false);
        imageView_listNews = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_listNews);
        ratingBar_news_list = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar_news_list);
    }
    News news = getNews(position);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewNews)).setText(news.textNews);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDateNews)).setText(news.dateNews);

    Picasso.with(this.context).load(news.imageURL).into(imageView_listNews);
    //* рейинг н6овости в списке
    ratingBar_news_list.setRating(news.rating_news_list);

    return view;
}

News getNews(int position) {
    return ((News) getItem(position));
}
```

ПОМОГИТЕ!!!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515637

Comment: Спасибо, но Нет. Пробовал уже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В родительский layout, который находится в list_news_adapter попробуйте добавить этот атрибут:

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Comment: Это наверное самый счастливый день))))))))))))))

Comment: Видимо долго ковырялись)

Comment: Да ну пипец просто. Мозг вынесло.Думал уже все крыша съедет)